# Construct vaadin 14 Textfield which accepts only numbers nothing else

Tags: java, vaadin

I need to make the vaadin 14 textfield which can accept only numbers.The criterias for the textfield are as follows

1.The textfield must only accept numbers nothing else as I want to use that textfield as a mobile number field.
2.validate in such a way that if users tries to enter the alphabets nothing must be reflected in the textfield.Only numbers must be allowed to be entered in the textfield.
3.Any warning or errors must not be shown in the UI as we are specially making textfield for the mobile number.

Things I have tried is binders but that allows to enter the alphabets later on after the focus lost event they validate and provide the error message I dont want that behaviour.

Also tried vaadin number field but that allows character 'e'

Just simple and straight forward I am looking for the textfield which takes input only numbers.If user tries to input alphabets nothing must be reflected in the textfield.

Comment: Can you provide the code you have tried up till now

Comment: TextField textField = new TextField("Mobile number");
binder.forField(textField
        .withValidator(new RegexpValidator("Not a valid mobile  number",
                "\\d*"))
        .bind(Person::getMobileNumber, Person::setMobileNumber);
binder.setBean(person);

Comment: Actually I needed a textfield like it would accept only numbers here by using binders we will allow user to put the value like alphabets and later on focus lost event the binders will be active and will validate it that i dont want i want straight way that user must only enter the numbers nothing else than digits.

Comment: @kushalbaldev Provide details as edits to your Question rather than as Comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Server-side

There are number of options you can do, the first one is the server side validator already mentioned in the [answer by Alim Özdemir](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58669543/642706):

```
binder.forField(textFieldForNumber)
      .withValidator(new RegexpValidator("Only 1-9 allowed","\\d*"))
      .bind(YourEntity::getNo, YourEntity::setNo);
```

## Client-side

There is also possibility do the same checking and input filtering on client side using [textField.setPattern(..)](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.0.11/com/vaadin/flow/component/textfield/TextField.html#setPattern-java.lang.String-) method, e.g.:

```
textFieldForNumber.setPattern("\\d*");
```

Furthermore it is possible to prevent input not matching the pattern alltogether by

```
textFieldForNumber.setPreventInvalidInput(true);
```

## Alternate widget: `NumberField`

Third alternative is to use the [*NumberField*](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-number-field) component.

Comment: Hi @Tatu Lund while setting pattern we are actually showing user the error while he puts an invalid keycode but i just want like i dont want users to enter the false keycode that is when user tries to put alphabets nothing must be reflected in the textfield.

Comment: To be more straight forward I just need a textfield in which we can enter only numbers nothing else. And by using binders it will allow me to put alphabets and then on the focus lost event it will validate in case i want that if one must press alphabets nothing must be entered in the textfield.

Comment: @kushalBaldev I added mention setPreventInvalidInput(true) to answer

Comment: yes its good and solution seems to be working Actually I was worried if I need to carry out the server side validations by applying pattern but its good that it works on both side thanks @Tatu Lund.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a validation on the field with the binder like

```
binder.forField(textFieldForNumber)
      .withValidator(new RegexpValidator("Only 1-9 allowed","\\d*"))
      .bind(YourEntity::getNo, YourEntity::setNo);
```

Comment: Hi @Alim Ozdemir while setting pattern we are actually showing user the error while he puts an invalid keycode but i just want like i dont want users to enter the false keycode.

Comment: @Basil Bourque I just upated my question hope it helps  you to get clear understanding.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for my answer I extracted the source code for the Integer text field In Vaadin new beta version

The code goes as follows

```
@Tag("vaadin-integer-field")
@HtmlImport("frontend://bower_components/vaadin-text-field/src/vaadin-integer-field.html")
@JsModule("@vaadin/vaadin-text-field/src/vaadin-integer-field.js")
public class BigIntegerField extends AbstractNumberField<BigIntegerField, BigInteger> {

    private static final SerializableFunction<String, BigInteger> PARSER = valueFormClient -> {
        if (valueFormClient == null || valueFormClient.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        try {
            return new BigInteger(valueFormClient);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return null;
        }
    };

    private static final SerializableFunction<BigInteger, String> FORMATTER = valueFromModel -> valueFromModel == null
            ? ""
            : valueFromModel.toString();

    /**
     * Constructs an empty {@code IntegerField}.
     */
    public BigIntegerField() {

          super(PARSER, FORMATTER, Double.MIN_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
  //      super(PARSER, FORMATTER, new BigInteger(String.valueOf(Integer.MIN_VALUE)), new BigInteger(String.valueOf(Integer.MAX_VALUE)));
    }

    /**
     * Constructs an empty {@code IntegerField} with the given label.
     *
     * @param label
     *            the text to set as the label
     */
    public BigIntegerField(String label) {
        this();
        setLabel(label);
    }

    /**
     * Constructs an empty {@code IntegerField} with the given label and
     * placeholder text.
     *
     * @param label
     *            the text to set as the label
     * @param placeholder
     *            the placeholder text to set
     */
    public BigIntegerField(String label, String placeholder) {
        this(label);
        setPlaceholder(placeholder);
    }

    /**
     * Constructs an empty {@code IntegerField} with a value change listener.
     *
     * @param listener
     *            the value change listener
     *
     * @see #addValueChangeListener(ValueChangeListener)
     */
    public BigIntegerField(
            ValueChangeListener<? super ComponentValueChangeEvent<BigIntegerField, BigInteger>> listener) {
        this();
        addValueChangeListener(listener);
    }

    /**
     * Constructs an empty {@code IntegerField} with a value change listener and
     * a label.
     *
     * @param label
     *            the text to set as the label
     * @param listener
     *            the value change listener
     *
     * @see #setLabel(String)
     * @see #addValueChangeListener(ValueChangeListener)
     */
    public BigIntegerField(String label,
            ValueChangeListener<? super ComponentValueChangeEvent<BigIntegerField, BigInteger>> listener) {
        this(label);
        addValueChangeListener(listener);
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a {@code IntegerField} with a value change listener, a label
     * and an initial value.
     *
     * @param label
     *            the text to set as the label
     * @param initialValue
     *            the initial value
     * @param listener
     *            the value change listener
     *
     * @see #setLabel(String)
     * @see #setValue(Object)
     * @see #addValueChangeListener(ValueChangeListener)
     */
    public BigIntegerField(String label, BigInteger initialValue,
            ValueChangeListener<? super ComponentValueChangeEvent<BigIntegerField, BigInteger>> listener) {
        this(label);
        setValue(initialValue);
        addValueChangeListener(listener);
    }

    /**
     * Sets the minimum value of the field. Entering a value which is smaller
     * than {@code min} invalidates the field.
     * 
     * @param min
     *            the min value to set
     */
    public void setMin(int min) {
        super.setMin(min);
    }

    /**
     * Gets the minimum allowed value of the field.
     *
     * @return the min property of the field
     * @see #setMin(int)
     */
    public int getMin() {
        return (int) getMinDouble();
    }

    /**
     * Sets the maximum value of the field. Entering a value which is greater
     * than {@code max} invalidates the field.
     *
     * @param max
     *            the max value to set
     */
    public void setMax(int max) {
        super.setMax(max);
    }

    /**
     * Gets the maximum allowed value of the field.
     *
     * @return the max property of the field
     * @see #setMax(int)
     */
    public int getMax() {
        return (int) getMaxDouble();
    }

    /**
     * Sets the allowed number intervals of the field. This specifies how much
     * the value will be increased/decreased when clicking on the
     * {@link #setHasControls(boolean) control buttons}. It is also used to
     * invalidate the field, if the value doesn't align with the specified step
     * and {@link #setMin(int) min} (if specified by user).
     * 
     * @param step
     *            the new step to set
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     *             if the argument is less or equal to zero.
     */
    public void setStep(int step) {
        if (step <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The step cannot be less or equal to zero.");
        }
        super.setStep(step);
    }

    /**
     * Gets the allowed number intervals of the field.
     *
     * @return the step property of the field
     * @see #setStep(int)
     */
    public int getStep() {
        return (int) getStepDouble();
    }

}
```

This Actually solved my problem regarding the Mobile number inputs.